# Accessing element from reference array in F#

Tags: f#

Was experimenting with arrays and references - my intent is to create a reference to an array and then use that reference inside a closure to access a certain element of the array. FSI attempt:

```
> let dk2 = Array.create 5 0
let dk2ref = ref dk2;;

val dk2 : int [] = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]
val dk2ref : int [] ref = {contents = [|0; 0; 0; 0; 0|];}

> !dk2ref.[1]

stdin(3,2): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined
```

Is there a direct way to access the element of a referenced array? (In this case, the 2nd element of dk2ref)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need a reference array.

Looking up the [operator precedence table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx), `.` operator has higher precedence than `!` operator. So your example is parsed as `!(dk2ref.[1])` which causes the error because `'a ref` doesn't implement [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx).

You just need to add parentheses at the right places:

```
> (!dk2ref).[1]
val it : int = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I was mainly experimenting with the use of references and arrays.